# Tensorflow : Restored variables have unexpected shape

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

When i saved my tensorflow model and restored it, it has wrong shaped variables and I can't figure out why.

here is my code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name="Y")
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name="bias")

hypo = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W) +b)

cost = -tf.reduce_mean(Y*(tf.log*(hypo)) + (1-Y)*(tf.log(1-hypo)))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

#### Saving model
SAVER_DIR = "model"
saver = tf.train.Saver()
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(SAVER_DIR, "model")
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(SAVER_DIR)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for step in range(2001):
    cost_val, hy_val, _ = sess.run([cost, hypo, train], feed_dict={X:x_dat, Y=y_dat})

saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=step)
```

The input data, "x_dat" is consisted of two columns, and "y_dat" is a single column.

I made [?, 2] shaped placeholder "X", and [2, 1] Variable "W".

After that, I restored model and checked the shape with this code:

```
#### Restoring model
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model/model-2000.meta')
saver.restore(sess,'./model/model-2000')

op = sess.graph.get_operations()
for m in op :
    print(m.values())
```

Result:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'X:0' shape=(?, 1) dtpye=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'Y:0' shape=(?, 1) dtpye=float32>,)
...
(<tf.Tensor 'weight:0' shape=(1, 1) dtpye=float32_ref>,)
...
(<tf.Tensor 'bias:0' shape=(1,) dtpye=float32_ref>,)
```

Why the X and weight tensor are shaped differently compared to the model I saved?
And how can I use the input data as two columns about this restored model?